# Inserting row based on string match

Tags: mysql

I am inserting the following rows into this table called `tb_price`

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | pair_id | price   |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  |         | 318.18  |
+----+---------+---------+
| 2  |         | 15.24   |
+----+---------+---------+
| 3  |         | 5963.13 |
+----+---------+---------+
```

When I insert the price, I want to be able to also insert the field `pair_id` by looking up the the `id` field in the table `tb_pair`

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | base_cur | quote_cur |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 1  | BTC      | USD       |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 2  | ETH      | USD       |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 3  | XMR      | USD       |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

When inserting into `tb_price` I have `base_cur` and `quote_cur` values available to me. Using the data: `base_cur = BTC`, `quote_cur = USD` and `price = 5963.13` I want to be able to populate `tb_price` as such (see ID 3):

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | pair_id | price   |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  |         | 318.18  |
+----+---------+---------+
| 2  |         | 15.24   |
+----+---------+---------+
| 3  | 1       | 5963.13 |
+----+---------+---------+
```

I am attempting to do this in a simple `INSERT` query but I am struggling to search for answers as the problem is too abstract with my current knowledge. I imagine some type of INNER JOIN where the pair_id is found by doing a look up on `tb_pair`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tb_price ( `pair_id` , `price` ) VALUES ( ( SELECT id FROM tb_pair WHERE `base_cur` = 'ETH' LIMIT 1 ), '10.00' )
```

You will need to configure the base_cur from `ETH` to your currency and update `10.00` to the price. You'll likely need to add variable validation and what not but that should give you a good starting point that gets the job done.